# Passing parameters from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Hello] 
    @portfolio nvarchar(5), 
    @discount numeric(18,2), 
    @lowerlimit numeric(18,2), 
    @midlimit numeric(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT distinct 
        EntityDescription, 
        d.AmountDueInCurr * @discount as [1st part],
        d.AmountDueInCurr * (1 - @discount) as [2nd Part], 
        CASE WHEN d.AmountDueInCurr <= 0 THEN 'Solution 1'
             WHEN d.AmountDueInCurr between 0 and @lowerlimit THEN 'Solution 2'
             WHEN d.AmountDueInCurr between (@lowerlimit + 0.01) and @midlimit THEN CONCAT(@portfolio, '-01')
             WHEN d.AmountDueInCurr > (@midlimit+0.01) THEN CONCAT(@portfolio, '-02')
             ELSE 'Error' 
        END AS Solution_type
    FROM 
        T1 d
```

and I would like to pass parameters from Excel, using VBA as this one:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Portfolio As String
    Dim Discount As Single
    Dim lowerlimit As Single
    Dim midlimit As Single

    Portfolio = Sheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
    Popust = Sheets("Input").Range("B3").Value
    lowerlimit = Sheets("Input").Range("B4").Value
    midlimit = Sheets("Input").Range("B5").Value

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Hello_data").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "exec SP_Hello '" & Portfolio & "','" & Discount & "','" & lowerlimit & "','" & midlimit & "'"
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Hello_data").Refresh
    End With
    Worksheets(2).Activate
End Sub
```

Seems like no matter what I do (format, declare or Dim the variables/parameters), I always get the conversion data type error in Excel. I have tried everything from String to Double in excel as well as all numerical combinations in SQL, none of the combinations seem to work.

If I pass just the Portfolio parameter (string) which is nvarchar in the database, it goes well. As soon as I add a number, or a Date into the combination, conversion errors appear.

Comment: Try making all your proc parameter nvarchar, and convert them as needed in the proc code.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: As Tab Alleman said, you can convert all parameters in the sp as nvarchar or you will need to cast it in your code as double/decimal.

Comment: I have tried the suggested... Dim-ed all variables in excel as strings, formated cells as text in the sheet and declared parameters in SQL as nvarchar. Still i get the 'error converting nvarchar to numeric' error.
Is that possibly the error from code execution and it breaks because i am using nvarchar in the calulation step?

Comment: With the numeric types the command should be like "exec SP_Hello 'Portfolio Name as Text',112.45,123.45,123.45". As you see, the numbers are without the ' ' around. So try with the numeric types and `.CommandText = "exec SP_Hello '" & Portfolio & "'," & Str(Discount) & "," & Str(lowerlimit) & "," & Str(midlimit) & ""`

Comment: @AxelRichter this worked perfectly, except for one thing. The discount is expressed as a percentage and under the hood, that percentage is a decimal number (i.e. 30% is 0,3). Problem appears when VBA code tries to pass that value because it has a comma as a decimal separator, whereas SQL requires it to be a decimal dot.

Comment: So to be more precise, i want users to be able to enter the Discount in Percentage format, and for that value to be passed as a numeric parameter with decimal DOT.
When I look at the resulting table Connection text, it says `exec SP_Hello 'SB002', 0, 30, 1000'`, and this zero should be 0.3

Comment: Where is `Discount` coming from? This is not shown in your code.

Comment: I have edited the VBA part of the question, i had a typo, used Popust instead of Discount.

Comment: So `Discount` is `Sheets("Input").Range("B3").Value`? What gets  `Debug.Print Discount: Debug.Print Str(Discount)`?

Comment: Double checked everything, had one more typo. now everything works. @AxelRichter, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored proc parameters have numeric data types defined, but your TSQL string built is passing in strings.  You need to remove the single quote you are placing around parameters `@discount`, `@lowerlimit` and `@midlimit`.

To see the issue, simply add this code:

```
Dim tsql As String
tsql = "exec SP_Hello '" & Portfolio & "','" & Discount & "','" & lowerlimit & "','" & midlimit & "'"
```

Print out tsql, and execute it in SSMS.  You should see the issue right away.